# How Seblod affects the work of authorization in Joomla

Tags: email, joomla

I'm using latest version of Joomla and Seblod on my test project. I need to get the email of the administrator of multisite. My Joomla works with two test sites in one Joomla. Documentation of Seblod is poor. Now I'm searching fragment of code, that can be used to calculate authorization.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    $CurrentSiteGroups = JCckDatabase::loadColumn( 'SELECT groups FROM #__cck_core_sites WHERE name = "'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'"' );

                    $AdminsGroups = JCckDatabase::loadColumn( 'SELECT id FROM #__usergroups WHERE id in (' . implode(',', $CurrentSiteGroups) . ') AND title LIKE "%Administrator%"');

                    $AdminsId = JCckDatabase::loadColumn( 'SELECT user_id FROM #__user_usergroup_map WHERE group_id in (' . implode(',', $AdminsGroups) . ')');

                    foreach($AdminsId as $AdminId){
                        $SiteAdmin = JCck::getUser($AdminId);
                        array_push($dest,$SiteAdmin->email);
                    }                                                

        JFactory::getMailer()->sendMail( $from, $fromName, $dest, $subject, $body, $format, $cc, $bcc, $attach, $reply_to, $reply_to_name );
```